# Yii2 : Add empty row at the top of the table using kartik\gridview

Tags: gridview, yii2, kartik-v

I'm trying to insert an empty row at the top of the table with the [yii2-kartik\gridview](https://demos.krajee.com/grid), so that I can add custom components to each column.

I would like the result to be as follows in the print:

[image]
So far I've only managed to insert this line by adding the `filterModel`:

```
<?php
    $gridViewPesquisaPonto = GridView::widget([
        'moduleId' => 'gridview',
        'dataProvider' => $pesquisaPontodataProvider,
        'filterModel' => true, // The table row containing the filters is configured here
        'layout' => "{items}{summary}{pager}",
        'captionOptions' => ['class' => 'text-wrap'],
        'options' => [
            'id' => 'grid-pontos-pesquisa',
        ],
        'columns' => [
            // ...
```

However, this line is exclusive for the use of filters implemented by the gridview. I would like to know a way to insert a line so that I can edit it freely (If you have the link to the documentation that contains this answer, please post in the answer, as I haven't found it yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `beforeRow` option of the `GridView` which takes a closure

```php
function ($model, $key, $index, $grid)
```

where

- `$model`: the current data model being rendered
- `$key`: the key value associated with the current data model
- `$index`: the zero-based index of the data model in the model array returned by [[dataProvider]]
- `$grid`: the `GridView` object

You can use the `$index` to identify if its the first row and add your custom row like below

```
'beforeRow'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $grid){
    if($index===0){
        return "<tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        </tr>";
    }

},
```

Remember to add or reduce the `<td>` columns to match the number of columns in your gridview.

Answer (score 1):

I will extend the **Muhammad Omer Aslam** answer with this one. I guess this will be more dynamic and does not require to adjust all times the number of columns that needs to be showed.

You can use the `beforeRow` option of the `GridView` which takes a closure

```
function ($model, $key, $index, $grid)
```

So here we can grab all model attributes and even check them before to display

```
'beforeRow'=>function ($model){
    $row = "<tr>";
    //loop thru attributes
    foreach($model->attributes as $key => $value){
        $row .= "<td>" . $key . "</td>";
    }
    return $row .= "</tr>";
},
```

Hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, for sure this tip was very useful!

Comment: the OP never told what he wanted in those columns so i added the numbers only, as his main question was how to add a row there.